# С# проверка параметров

Tags: c#, массивы, проверка

Помогите. Как сделать проверку, передается ли в метод хоть какое то числовое значение?

```
public static bool FindMinMax(int[][] array, out int min, out int 
    max)
{
    min = int.MinValue;
    max = int.MaxValue;


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не ясно, что вы хотите проверить? Приведите хотя бы пример "инвалидного" вызова метода.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker интересно, а что вы тут кроме входного массива можете еще проверить?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я уточнил, чтобы отредактировать заголовок, ведь содержание вопроса с названием "Доброго времени суток. С# проверка" предельно ясно.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Ну так скажите это в лоб, а то я на 100% уверен, что и автору тоже показался ваш вопрос странным, ведь вопрос поставлен четко и ясно, код тоже не имеет чего либо лишнего. Вы небось ему еще и минус влепили без объяснений. Не делается так (ИМХО).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ лол, вы бы поменьше предполагали (или тут так принято?), я ничего не ставил. Я попросил привести пример - это очень сложная и туманная просьба?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Скорей весь ваш комментарий туманный (лишь мое мнение). Про минус, это мои предположения, не более (если не ваш, то извините). Дальнейшую дискуссию не вижу смысла разводить, я лишь считаю ваш комментарий непонятным и бессмысленным, не более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если не знаете - не тыкайте пальцем в меня или кого-либо еще, я в этом тоже смысловой нагрузки с вашей стороны не вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static bool FindMinMax(int[][] array, out int min, out int max)
{
  min = int.MaxValue;
  max = int.MinValue;

  if (array == null || array.Length == 0) 
    return false;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь судари )

Comment: @ВикторГилевич Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: самое очевидное не заметил )